# Valor selecionado pelo selectOneMenu vem nulo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um selectOneMenu que contem uma lista de tipos de documentos, que eu associo aos documentos que estão sendo anexados em um p:fileUpload, entretanto, o valor selecionado pelo selectOneMenu vem nulo

**View de Anexo de Arquivos**

```
<p:dialog id="dialogAnexos" minHeight="70" header="Anexar Arquivos"
                              widgetVar="dialogAnexos">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Tipo de Documento *:" style="font-weight: bold" />


                        <h:selectOneMenu style="height: 20px; width: 200px; background-color: #fff;"
                                         value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.tipoDocumentoSelecionado}"
                                         required="true" requiredMessage="Tipo de Documento: Selecione uma Opção...">

                            <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Selecione..." />

                            <f:selectItems value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.obterTiposDocumentos()}" />

                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <h:outputLabel value="Anexo de Arquivos *:" style="font-weight: bold" />

                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <p:fileUpload id="uploadAnexo"
                              fileUploadListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.handleFileUpload}"
                              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)$/"
                              sizeLimit="10000000"
                              label="Escolher..."
                              multiple="true"
                              auto="true"
                              showButtons="false"
                              mode="advanced"
                              uploadLabel="Enviar Arquivos"
                              process="@this"
                              dragDropSupport="true"
                              required="true"
                              requiredMessage="Anexe pelo menos um arquivo"/>

                        <p:commandButton value="Enviar" onclick="dialogAnexos.hide();" immediate="true"/>
                    </p:dialog>
```

**Método que preenche a Lista de Tipos de Documentos**

```
public Map<String, Object> obterTiposDocumentos() {
   Map<String, Object> tiposDocumentos = new HashMap();

   tiposDocumentos.put("CNPJ", "CNPJ");
   tiposDocumentos.put("Contrato", "Contrato");

   return tiposDocumentos;
  }
```

**HandleFileUpload, onde o tipo de documento é associado com o arquivo anexado**

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
   UploadedFile item = event.getFile();

   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   mes++;
   String complementoDir = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + mes + "/" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/";
   String sDiretorio = SistemaConstante.CAMINHO_ARQUIVOS_REGISTRO_ON_LINE_EMPRESA + complementoDir;
   String sCaminho = SistemaConstante.DIRETORIO_ARQUIVOS_REGISTRO_ON_LINE_EMPRESA + complementoDir;
   String nomeArquivo = item.getFileName().replace("\\", File.separator).replaceAll(" ", "_");

   File diretorio = new File(sDiretorio);

   boolean diretorioCriado = true;

   if (!diretorio.exists()) {
       if (!diretorio.mkdir()) {
           if (!diretorio.mkdirs()) {
               FacesUtils.mensFatal("Falha na criação do diretório!");
               diretorioCriado = false;
           }
       }
  }

  if(diretorioCriado) {
      String aux = StringUtil.removerAcentos(nomeArquivo);
      String caminhoArquivo = sDiretorio + aux;
      String caminhoVerArquivo = sCaminho + aux;
      File arquivo = new File(caminhoArquivo);

      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);
      out.write(item.getContents());
      out.close();

      arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa = new ArquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa();
      arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa.setCaminhoArquivo(caminhoArquivo);
      arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa.setCaminhoVerArquivo(caminhoVerArquivo);
      arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa.setTipoDocumento(tipoDocumentoSelecionado);
      arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresaDao.salvar(arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa);
      arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa.setNomeArquivo(aux);
      arquivosRegistroOnlineEmpresa.add(arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, fiz umas modificações no converter e funcionou

```
@FacesConverter(value = "tipoDocumentoConverter")
public class TipoDocumentoConverter implements javax.faces.convert.Converter {

     public TipoDocumentoConverter() {
     }

     @Override
     public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String string) {
     if (string == null) {
          return null;
     }

         Long id = Long.parseLong(string);
         TipoDocumento tipoDocumento = new TipoDocumento();
         // tipoDocumento.setDescricao(string);
         tipoDocumento.setIdTipoDocumento(id);
         return tipoDocumento;
     }

     @Override
     public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object) {
         if (object == null) {
             return null;
         }

         if (object instanceof TipoDocumento) {
             TipoDocumento t = (TipoDocumento) object;
             // return "" + t.getDescricao();
             return "" + t.getIdTipoDocumento();
         } else {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("object:" + object + "of type:"
            + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type:br.org.creapi.entities.TipoDocumento");
        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema seja no momento que você está avaliando a variável.

O método `handleFileUpload` é chamado imediatamente após o upload do arquivo e neste momento como o seu formulário por inteiro não foi submetido o valor do `tipoDocumentoSelecionado` é nulo.

Acredito que a solução mais simples no seu caso seja fazer com que o valor do tipo de documento selecionado seja enviado a cada mudança, você pode fazer isso adicionando um evento ajax no onChange do selectOneMenu.

Também sugeriria que você utiliza-se o selectOneMenu do primefaces.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.tipoDocumentoSelecionado}" required="true" requiredMessage="Tipo de Documento: Selecione uma Opção...">
    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Selecione..." />
    <f:selectItems value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.obterTiposDocumentos()}" />

    <p:ajax event="change" />

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Sugeriria também que você colocasse um `<h:form>` envolvendo o seu selectOneMenu e o fileupload.